# How to clean up a 30million record table

Tags: php, mysql

We have a table on our database that tracks user behavior.
Basically each page that the user views we track this.

In the table we have the following:

```
id | user_id | user_ip | page | created_on
```

When a user checks the site from PC and let's say he checks a specific article the system saves under "page" the following "/article/specific/slug" however if the user checks the same page from the mobile version of the website it saves "http://m.website.com/article/specific/slug"

We are looking to change this.

We have added a new field in the database as enum (pc, m) and therefore we want regardless of device to save under "page" always "/article/specific/slug"

One issue is that we now have 30 million records in the past that need to be converted.

Meaning we write a query that checks if "http://m.website.com" exists update the field removing the "http://m.website.com" and making the "device" field updated as "m".

Can someone please help with this?

Comment: What is the question? How to write that query? Or how to execute it against the 30 million rows table on a live server?

Comment: The question is both actually I need the query but something that we can actually run on 30 million rows.

Comment: If the load on MySQL is a concern, you could always dump the table to a file, use command line tools such as `sed` to make the changes (perhaps even on a different server) then import the table from file

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
update visits_table
set
    page=replace(page, 'http://m.website.com', ''),
    device='m'
where
    page like 'http://m.website.com%';
```

To go through 30 mil rows you'll have to... go through 30 mil rows. So you'll either do it just with the above query either:

- when the site is down for maintenance
- when the site has low traffic (e.g early morning hours?)
- whenever you want, but expect some stress on the mysql until it's done (it may take a while)

Otherwise, if your ids are incremental, you can update in batches by splitting the query in many queries. e.g:

```
update ... where ... and id between 1 and 1000000;
update ... where ... and id between 1000001 and 2000000;
update ... where ... and id between 2000001 and 3000000;
...
```